# How to animate a "movie style" credit reel with tkinter and canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a "movie" style credit reel using tkinter's canvas. I'd like to iterate through a list of names and have them scroll across the window. While I've successfully gotten a single name to scroll, I'm struggling to iterate over several names.

I appreciate your help and apologies for any gross oversights on my part.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

window = Tk()
window.geometry("1920x1080")
window.title("Window 1")

canvas1 = Canvas(window, width=1920, height=1080, bg="green", bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
canvas1.pack()


class CreditList:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.location = 1080

    def credit_roll_function(self):
        text = canvas1.create_text(960,self.location, text=self.text, anchor=S, fill="black",
                                   font="Time 40")
        while True:
            canvas1.move(text, 0, -3)
            window.update()
            time.sleep(.03)


credit_list = ["First Name", "Second Name", "Third Name"]

for credit in credit_list:
    item = CreditList(credit)
    item.credit_roll_function()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The while loop in your function will block the main loop of tkinter till it's done. Your workaround via update can lead to various bugs and is discouraged. As an alternative, I suggest you to hold a frame with the desired Labels or using the Text widget and use built-in scrollcommand in an root.after coroutine.

Comment: i think your best bet is rasterizing the names on a PIL canvas, every defined time interval.

Comment: @Thingamabobs: since it's just a list of strings, using an embedded frame is more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: @AhmedAEK: why do you think that's a good solution? The canvas is designed to have text items on it.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, I just jumped to the large case of 100s of lines which rasterizing all at once would be a bad idea, so having a canvas which you sequentially drawn on is a good idea, but i guess it's overengineered for small cases.

Comment: @AhmedAEK: the canvas can easily handle many thousands of items.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, not really, the current solution will crash somewhere after 400-700 names as it is trying to rasterize them all at once, hopefully he won't need more.

Comment: @AhmedAEK: yes, really. The current solution is flawed. A proper solution will work for thousands of items. The solution I posted as an answer easily handles 2,000 lines of text

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way to do it that uses the universal widget [`after()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) method instead of calling `time.sleep()` which interferes with tkinter's `mainloop()`. Each time the class' `roll_credits()` method is called, it moves the text upward a little and schedules another call to itself if the text isn't at the top of the window yet.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *


class CreditList:
    def __init__(self, lines):
        self.location = HEIGHT
        self.text = canvas.create_text(0, 0, text='\n'.join(lines), justify=CENTER,
                                       anchor=NW, fill='black', font='Time 40')
        xl, yt, xr, yb = canvas.bbox(self.text)
        txtwidth = xr - xl
        xpos = (WIDTH-txtwidth) // 2  # To center text horizontally.
        canvas.move(self.text, xpos, self.location)


    def roll_credits(self):
        xl, yt, xr, yb = canvas.bbox(self.text)
        if yb <= 0:  # Completely off top of screen?
            canvas.pack_forget()
            tk.Button(text='Done', font=('Courier New', 20), relief=GROOVE, bg='orange',
                      command=window.quit).place(x=WIDTH/2, y=HEIGHT/2)
            return  # Stop.
        canvas.move(self.text, 0, -3)
        window.after(DELAY, self.roll_credits)  # Keep going.


DELAY = 25  # Millisecs.

window = tk.Tk()
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
window.update_idletasks()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = window.winfo_width(), window.winfo_height()  # Get screen size.
window.geometry(f'{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}+0+0')
window.title('Window 1')

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='green', bd=0,
                    highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
canvas.pack()

credits = 'First Name', 'Second Name', 'Third Name'
cl = CreditList(credits)
window.after(DELAY, cl.roll_credits)  # Start rolling credits "loop".
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give all of your text items the same tag, you can move them all at the same time. Another solution is to create a single text item that is created by joining all of your strings with a newline.

For example, the following code illustrates how to create all of the items with a given tag, then moves them all one pixel at a time every 33 ms until they no longer are visible.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class CreditList(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

    def roll_credits(self, credit_list):
        x = self.winfo_width() // 2
        y = self.winfo_height()
        temp = self.create_text(0,0,text="Hello")
        bbox = self.bbox(temp)
        self.delete(temp)
        lineheight = bbox[3]-bbox[1]
        linespacing = 4

        for credit in credit_list:
            self.create_text(x, y, text=credit, anchor="n", tags=("credit",))
            y += lineheight + linespacing

        self._animate()

    def _animate(self):
        self.move("credit", 0, -1)
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = self.bbox("credit")
        if y1 > 0:
            self.after(33, self._animate)

root = tk.Tk()
credits = CreditList(root)
credits.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

credit_list = 'First Name', 'Second Name', 'Third Name'
root.after(1000, credits.roll_credits, credit_list)

root.mainloop()
```